# Solve for stopping point of sum

Tags: summation

I am currently in 8th grade and in my Algebra class we are currently covering exponential growth, e.g. bacteria splitting, fruit fly growth, etc. Anyway, one exercise we did was on zombies. The problem started with 5 "sleeper cell" zombies, who each day could "turn" three humans. The equation looked like this: $5\times 3^x = h$

$h$ = humans infected each day.

While this was interesting, I wanted to see how many *total* infected humans there were *including* the original 5 "sleeper cell" zombies. I had a scientific calculator on hand so I calculated the sum of all of this with $\displaystyle \sum_{d=0}^{19}5(3)^d$ where $d = $ days passed.

This ended up being 8,716,961,000, a little more than the total Earth's population. Therefore $d>18$ but $d<19$ in order for the sum to $\approx$ 7,000,000,000 (Earth's population).

My question is, is it possible to solve for the stopping point of the sum/upper value of the sum? Please keep in mind that although I am in AP 8th grade math, I'm no mathematician, so please keep the explanations within the realm of my comprehension.

Comment: I calculated that the number of days required for you sum to add to the approximate world population of 7.13 billion would be $d\approx 18.8171$ which can be worked out using methods provided in the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is nice!

Okay let's say the sum for the first $n$ terms is $s_n$ (just forget about the 5 first):

$$ s_n = \sum_{i=0}^n 3^i $$ Then we know that:

$$ 3\cdot s_n =\sum_{i=0}^n3^{i+1} =3^1+3^2+3^3+\dots+3^{n+1} \\ s_n=\sum_{i=0}^n3^i=3^0+3^1+3^2+\dots+3^n$$

So let's substract those sums:

$$ s_n - 3\cdot s_n = \sum_{i=0}^n3^{i}-3^{i+1}=3^0+\underbrace{(-3^1+3^1)}_{=0}+(-3^2+3^2)+\cdots-3^{n+1} = 3^0-3^{n+1}$$

So then we know:

$$ s_n-3\cdot s_n = s_n(1-3) = 1-3^{n+1}$$
So let's just try to get the $n$:
$$ 3^{n+1} = 1+2s_n$$

Now we have to take the $\log_3$:

$$ n+1 = \log_3\left(1+2s_n\right) = \frac{\log(1+2s_n)}{\log(3)}$$

So wait we forgot the $5$ right, so your stopping value $S$ is five times bigger:
$$ S = 5\cdot s_n$$

Giving you the formula:

$$ n = \frac{\log\left(1+\frac{2}{5}S\right)}{\log(3)}-1 $$

Comment: Thanks! Your explanation was clear, although I'm curious how you went from $2s_n$ to $\frac{2}{5}S$. Could you please explain that?

Comment: you might notice that $s_n = \sum_{i=0}^n 3^i$ in your formula you asked for $\hat s_n = \sum_{i=0}^n 5\cdot 3^i$. 
after all it's a sum so $\hat s_n = 5\cdot s_n$. Giving us $s_n = \frac{1}{5}\hat s_n$

Comment: Oh, I see that now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think there's something not quite right about the equation $h=5\times3^x$.

Look at it this way.  You start day 1 with $5$ zombies.  Each of them "turns" three humans that day.  So at the end of the day you have the original $5$ zombies plus $15$ *new* zombies, for a total of $20$.  Now on day 2, those $20$ zombies each turn three humans, so at that end of the second day you have the $20$ zombies you started with plus $60$ new zombies, for a total of $80$.  At the end of day 3 you'll have $80+240=320$ zombies, and so forth.

The point is, zombies *don't die* (unless you shoot them in the head, of course).  So it seems to me that the basic equation is

$$Z(x)=\text{ the number of zombies at the end of day $x$ }=5\times4^x$$

If you want to know the number of humans turned on day $x$, you might write that as

$$h(x)=Z(x)-Z(x-1)=5(4^x-4^{x-1})=15\times4^{x-1}$$

But the total number of humans turned by the end of day $x$ is simply

$$Z(x)-5=5(4^x-1)$$

If you want to know when this number exceeds the population of the Earth, note that $4^5=2^{10}\approx1000$, hence $4^{15}=2^{30}\approx1$ billion.  Multiplying by $5$ and comparing to the approximate human population of $7$ billion, we see that the zombies run out of people to turn on the 16th day.

Comment: I think you may be misunderstanding the question. The table was showing the number of humans that *get* turned each day, not the total number of zombies at the end of the day.

Comment: @MiloGosnell, what table?  I was just taking seriously the description of the problem as specifying that each zombie turns three humans each day.  The only way to understand the equation $h=5\times3^x$ is to assume that zombies die after they turn their three humans (who become zombies and die after they each turn another three humans, and so forth).

Comment: Sorry, not table, I meant problem, but this doesn't answer my question, this just solves my problem. Also I did not write the problem, it was given to us by our teacher. Perhaps she wasn't thinking clearly.

Answer (score 0):

This is a [geometric series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series)  The general equation, if $r$ is the ratio between the terms ($3$ for you) is $\sum_{i=1}^d r^i=\frac {r^{d+1}-1}{r-1}$  You can distribute out the $5$.   You can use logaritms to solve for $d$